# search bar on table with javascript

Tags: javascript, searchbar

In the search bar that I created in the project table, when `<td>` is the last row of the table, it works correctly and does not display the error message that I set for this case, but when the `<td`> values that are not in the last row, for example, in the rows I search before the end and an error message displays. How can I write a better code for the search bar with JavaScript?

```
function search() {
    let input, filter, table, tr, td, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("search");
    filter = input.value;
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
            txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
            if (txtValue.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].classList.remove("hidden");
                document.getElementById("error-message").classList.add("hidden");
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("error-message").classList.remove("hidden");
                tr[i].classList.add("hidden");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

codes in html :

```
    @model IEnumerable<ProvinceLevel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "مدیریت - نمایش سطح استان";
}
<div class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm  my-1 mx-3">نمایش سطح استان</div>
<div class="row m-0 p-0">
    <div class="col-md-5 p-0 ml-3">
        <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control w-100" placeholder="نام کاربری" maxlength="10" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="btn btn-info mx-1" onclick="search()">جست و جو</button>
    </div>
</div>

<table id="myTable" class="table border table-striped table-bordered mt-2 mx-auto table-custom--2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>نام کاربری</th>
            <th>رمز عبور</th>
            <th>نام</th>
            <th>نام خانوادگی</th>
            <th>نفش</th>
            <th>جنسیت</th>
            <th>وضعیت استخدامی</th>
            <th>کارکرد</th>
            <th>بیمه</th>
            <th>امتیاز</th>
            <th>شماره تماس</th>
            <th>وضعیت تاهل</th>
            <th>آدرس محل سکونت</th>
            <th>حذف</th>
            <th>ویرایش</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.nationalCode</td>
                <td>@item.userPass</td>
                <td>@item.fName</td>
                <td>@item.lName</td>
                <td>@item.role</td>
                <td>@item.gender</td>
                <td>@item.employmentStatus</td>
                <td>@item.workingStatus</td>
                <td>@item.insuranceStatus</td>
                <td>@item.score</td>
                <td>@item.tel</td>
                <td>@item.maritalStatus</td>
                <td>@item.address</td>
                <td><a><img src="~/icons/clear-icon.png" /></a></td>
                <td><a><img src="~/icons/edit-icon.png" /></a></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="mx-auto my-5 w-25 hidden" id="error-message">
    <div class="alert alert-warning text-center border border-warning">کاربر مورد نظر یافت نشد</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Display an error message when nothing is found for the search and do not display it in other cases

Comment: Thank you for posting your JavaScript, could you also share your (relevant, "*[mcve]*") HTML, with some sample content in order that we can recreate your problem without having to make assumptions as to your DOM structure, or function calls.

Comment: Hello David,
I put both the image of the bug and the html code

Answer (score 0):

One approach is as follows, with explanatory comments in the code:

```js
// a named Arrow function, which takes one argument - passed automatically
// from the EventTarget.addEventListener() method:
const search = (evt) => {

  // initialising a reference to the <input> element, retrieved
  // via its id:
  let input = document.getElementById('search'),
    // retrieving the current value of the <input> element,
    // using document.querySelector and using
    // String.prototype.trim() to remove leading, and
    // trailing white-space from the value:
    value = input.value.trim(),
    // using document.querySelector() to retrieve the first
    // element on the page matching the supplied CSS selector
    // (this will return null if no element is found):
    tableBody = document.querySelector('#myTable tbody'),
    // retrieving the rows collection within the tableBody
    // element, and using an Array-literal and spread-
    // syntax to convert the iterable collection to
    // an Array of <tr> element-nodes:
    rows = [...tableBody.rows];

  // iterating over the Array of nodes, using
  // Array.prototype.forEach(), passing a
  // reference to the current <tr> element to
  // the function body:
  rows.forEach(
    (row) => {
      // caching a reference to the firstElementChild:
      let firstCell = row.firstElementChild,
        // using String.prototype.includes() to determine
        // whether the <tr> element's textContent
        // property includes the entered value; if
        // included this evaluates to true, if not
        // included this evaluates to false:
        included = firstCell.textContent.includes(value);

      // if the value was/is included we wish to retain
      // the visibility of the current <tr>, therefore we
      // invert the Boolean using the not operator so that
      // rows containing the value are retained, and not hidden
      // while those rows not containing the value (in which
      // 'included' would be false) is hidden:
      row.hidden = !included;
    });

  // here we use the rows Array, using Array.prototype.filter()
  // to retain only those <tr> elements that are hidden:
  let hiddenRows = rows.filter((r) => r.hidden === true),
    // and here we compare the Array of <tr> elements to see
    // if it's exactly equal to the number of rows that
    // are hidden:
    allHidden = rows.length === hiddenRows.length;

  // here we retrieve the element with the id of 'error-message',
  // and update its "hidden" property to be the inverse of the
  // allHidden Boolean value; so that if all rows are hidden
  // the "not found" message is visible:
  document.getElementById('error-message').hidden = !allHidden;
}

// finding the the first <button> element on the page, and using
// EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the search() function
// (note the deliberate omission of parentheses) as the handler
// for the 'click' event:
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', search);
```

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid currentColor;
  border-spacing: 0;
  inline-size: clamp(30rem, 50%, 800px);
  margin-inline: auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th {
  border-block-end: 2px solid currentColor;
}

:is(th, td):first-child {
  text-align: start;
}

:is(th, td):not(:first-child) {
  text-align: end;
}

tbody tr {
  block-size: 1.8em;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: block-size 300ms linear, opacity 300ms linear;
}

#error-message {
  border: 2px solid currentColor;
  border-radius: 300vmax;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 2px #fff;
  color: #f00;
  margin-block: 1rem;
  padding-block: 0.25rem;
  padding-inline: 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="row m-0 p-0">
  <div class="col-md-5 p-0 ml-3">
    <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control w-100" placeholder="Name" maxlength="10">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <button class="btn btn-info mx-1">Search</button>
  </div>

  <table id="myTable" class="table border table-striped table-bordered mt-2 mx-auto table-custom--2">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>DoB</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Hussain, Mia</td>
        <td>11/12/1983</td>
        <td>39</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cai, Jameson</td>
        <td>9/27/1976</td>
        <td>46</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>He, Ivy</td>
        <td>4/19/1980</td>
        <td>42</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Singh, Ezra</td>
        <td>3/18/1987</td>
        <td>36</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kumar, Hailey</td>
        <td>2/3/1986</td>
        <td>37</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ceng, Sofia</td>
        <td>10/15/1974</td>
        <td>48</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>I, Kayden</td>
        <td>6/4/1996</td>
        <td>26</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Perez, Kayden</td>
        <td>7/30/1972</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hernandez, Jack</td>
        <td>7/7/1985</td>
        <td>37</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ding, Autumn</td>
        <td>9/26/1991</td>
        <td>31</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ding, Waylon</td>
        <td>10/25/2000</td>
        <td>22</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ahmed, Grace</td>
        <td>5/12/1985</td>
        <td>37</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ram, Isaac</td>
        <td>5/20/1973</td>
        <td>49</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tan, Audrey</td>
        <td>9/15/1981</td>
        <td>41</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tang, Emery</td>
        <td>6/28/1976</td>
        <td>46</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Chen, Sadie</td>
        <td>10/27/1998</td>
        <td>24</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ceng, Joseph</td>
        <td>6/19/1971</td>
        <td>51</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Nguyen, Noah</td>
        <td>10/25/1971</td>
        <td>51</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rodriguez, Elena</td>
        <td>6/22/1999</td>
        <td>23</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ahmed, Kayden</td>
        <td>7/15/1995</td>
        <td>27</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sun, Cooper</td>
        <td>9/21/1974</td>
        <td>48</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ye, Camila</td>
        <td>4/24/1985</td>
        <td>37</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Du, Nevaeh</td>
        <td>5/21/1994</td>
        <td>28</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dong, Nathan</td>
        <td>2/18/1981</td>
        <td>42</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bai, Ethan</td>
        <td>10/30/1996</td>
        <td>26</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zhou, Jaxon</td>
        <td>10/14/1971</td>
        <td>51</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kim, Josiah</td>
        <td>4/9/1992</td>
        <td>31</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Luo, Caleb</td>
        <td>5/8/1975</td>
        <td>47</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garcia, Willow</td>
        <td>9/23/1973</td>
        <td>49</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yuan, Claire</td>
        <td>8/9/1973</td>
        <td>49</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bibi, Lucas</td>
        <td>9/19/1979</td>
        <td>43</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yan, Zoey</td>
        <td>2/27/2000</td>
        <td>23</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Martinez, Colton</td>
        <td>7/1/1986</td>
        <td>36</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lopez, Ezra</td>
        <td>8/25/1978</td>
        <td>44</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yadav, Julian</td>
        <td>2/19/1971</td>
        <td>52</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cao, Legend</td>
        <td>6/23/1973</td>
        <td>49</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tang, Ezra</td>
        <td>5/26/1997</td>
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yu, Michael</td>
        <td>2/27/1995</td>
        <td>28</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Khan, Ethan</td>
        <td>6/12/1980</td>
        <td>42</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hassan, Autumn</td>
        <td>3/29/1968</td>
        <td>55</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ram, Henry</td>
        <td>3/9/1987</td>
        <td>36</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ram, Mateo</td>
        <td>9/21/1973</td>
        <td>49</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hassan, Riley</td>
        <td>11/29/1990</td>
        <td>32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lal, Luna</td>
        <td>9/1/1976</td>
        <td>46</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Huang, Nolan</td>
        <td>8/22/1976</td>
        <td>46</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garcia, Violet</td>
        <td>6/30/1984</td>
        <td>38</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mohammed, Ethan</td>
        <td>2/27/1977</td>
        <td>46</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tan, Lily</td>
        <td>5/5/1972</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zhao, Nevaeh</td>
        <td>3/27/1971</td>
        <td>52</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ceng, Jack</td>
        <td>5/1/1981</td>
        <td>41</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!-- I removed the 'hidden' class-name from the element, and instead chose to use
       the hidden attribute (this doesn't need a value, if the attribute is present
       the element will be hidden) -->
  <div class="mx-auto my-5 w-25" id="error-message" hidden>
    <div class="alert alert-warning text-center border border-warning">Not found</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/n70ktm2q/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/firstElementChild).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`HTMLElement.hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden).
- [Spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
- [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but when it doesn't find anything, I want to display an error message, what should I do? This function does not show this message at all.

Comment: If I type the letters "df" into the snippet in the answer, and click the button, all rows are hidden and the "not found" message is shown below the table. Does this not work for you?

Comment: No, nothing worked, only the rows are hidden and I want both the message to be displayed and the table header to be hidden

Comment: Can you tell me the exact steps you're taking to test the answer? Are you trying in the English language or in the original Persian (apologies if I'm wrong about the language)? Are there any errors reported in the browser console? If you inspect the DOM does the `error-message` have the `hidden` class-name still? Does it have the `hidden` attribute?

Comment: I want to display the error message in Farsi and it is still hidden, and I want the header to be hidden when it is displayed

Comment: Would you be able to give me examples of names written in Farsi, that way I can try to help (I hadn't considered the bias towards the Latin alphabet when writing the original answer).

Comment: کاربری یافت نشد.